# How can i specify SSL version in curb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, curl, ssl, curb

I am interacting with an API that requires SSL3.

From the command line I form the request like:

```
 curl -ssl3 -H 'Authorization: Bearer XXXX' https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/user/documentsv2
```

With curb I have implemented:

```
  c = Curl::Easy.new("https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/document") do |curl|
  curl.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer XXXX"
  curl.use_ssl = true
  curl.ssl_version = "ssl3"
    end
```

This `ssl_version` method seem like it should do the same thing as the `-ssl3` switch the error message that results is:

```
1.9.3-p286 :082 > c.perform
Curl::Err::SSLConnectError: Curl::Err::SSLConnectError
```

Do you know how to properly create the curb request?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the ssl flags require integers. this works.

```
c = Curl::Easy.new("https://capi-eval.signnow.com/api/documentsv2") do |curl|
  curl.headers["Bearer"] = "XXXX"
  curl.verbose = true
  curl.use_ssl = 3
  curl.ssl_version = 3
end
```